# UWP search in a ComboBox

Tags: xaml, combobox, uwp

I am making a UWP App in which I have a `ComboBox` with a lot of items. I want users to be able to jump to a particular item by typing in. I discovered  that using `IsTextSearchEnabled="True"` on the `ComboBox` does exactly what I want. But I am not sure how to use this property and the docs has no examples on it

```
   <ComboBox x:Name="BrowseBySourceComboBox"  
                                      SelectionChanged="BrowseBySourceComboBox_SelectionChanged"
                                      Grid.Row="1"                                          
                                      PlaceholderText="Select Source"      
                                      IsTextSearchEnabled="True"                                      
                                      Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxStyle}"
                                      ItemsSource="{x:Bind BrowseBySourceComboBoxList, Mode=OneWay}">
```

This is not giving any text box to type in.

Comment: Unfortunately the `IsEditable` property in `ComboBox` is *read-only*. Maybe try `AutoSuggestBox`?

Comment: @JustinXL https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.combobox#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_ComboBox_IsTextSearchEnabled

Comment: I am well aware of that link. What for?

Comment: I was referring to this: **Starting in Windows 10, version 1607, ComboBox introduces a text search feature. By default, the ComboBox jumps to a relevant value as the user types. You can set the IsTextSearchEnabled property to false to disable this behavior. This is useful, for example, if you have extended ComboBox with custom text search.**

Comment: I know... In WPF, you also need to set IsEditable to true. But this property is not available in UWP, that's what I am saying.

Comment: okay, that docs made me think otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But I am not sure how to use this property and the docs has no examples on it

According to the remarks of `IsTextSearchEnabled` property:

> Starting in Windows 10, version 1607, ComboBox introduces a text search feature. By default, the ComboBox jumps to a relevant value as the user types.

This feature enabled by default, you don't need set anything for the `Combobox` it will work if your windows 10 version is higher than 1607. For how it works, for example, as the following picture shows, when the `Comboxbox` get focused, I type `B` from the keyboard it will jump to `Blue`,  type `R` it will jump to red. More details you may reference slide 29 of [this ppt](https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/view.aspx?src=https%3A%2F%2Fsec.ch9.ms%2Fsessions%2Fbuild%2F2016%2FB853.pptx).

[image]

> This is not giving any text box to type in.

`Combobox` is not editable in UWP app. The `IsEditable` will always return false.  The `IsTextSearchEnabled` property worked without a editable area. If you want a control that has editable `TextBox` and as well a drop down list can be searched by text typed from the `TextBox`, the `AutoSuggestBox` is more fitter for you as @Justin XL said. [Here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlAutoSuggestBox) is the official sample of `AutoSuggestBox`.

Comment: Does this work when a collection of complex object is bound to the `ComboBox` or when the items inside the list is not sorted ? In my case it only works when a list of strings is bound to the `ComboBox`

Comment: @ravikumar To answer your question I would say that based on my experience, no, this does not work unless the ComboBox is bound to a simple string collection.

Comment: It actually does work even with complex items, but you have to override their `ToString` method to return the `string` property you want to use for the filtering.